# Max character count then overflow to next cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Creating a database, cells must be 250 character max, when entering data I want the first cell to allow 250 character max, as I continue to enter additional characters I want it to automatically overflow into the next adjacent cell until it reaches 250 characters again and then overflow again into the next adjacent cell. I have three columns established for this.

Comment: What have you tried already? This isn't a script writing service.

Comment: used length command but it only indicates number of characters in cell.

Comment: You mean you want the user to be able to type up to 750 characters, without doing anything to terminate that data entry (e.g., Enter, Tab, cursor key or mouse click), and have their entry automatically spread out over up to three columns? That might be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There IS a way with nothing special (no macros or other not... early-learning... functionalities):  Use two sheets.

On `Sheet 1` you enter the data, typing or pasting it into cells and on `Sheet 2` you have formulas that work on the entered data. The formulas will simply take the entry on `Sheet 1` and divide it as required. When done, with a batch or all of it, you will have to do one, or two, things. You will convert the formulas to values with `Paste|Special|Values`, then deal with the empty cells if your database needs true `NULL's` where "blanks" exist in Excel. I shall assume you need the second — just use the core of the formulas if not.

So, cell `Sheet1!A2` has data entered. Cells `A2:C2` on `Sheet 2` are to have the split apart data. You will test the proposed result of the core formula for being blank and return something that could NEVER occur if so. I will use a simple "PPP" in the formula but you could use higher Unicode characters, or the old 128-255 codes for border drawing perhaps.

Column A simply gets:

```
=LEFT(Sheet1!A2,250)
```

Column B gets:

```
=MID(Sheet1!A2,251,250)
```

Column 3 gets:

```
=MID(Sheet1!A2,501,250)
```

Note that Column 3 does not use `RIGHT()` as finding how many characters to use would be more complicated than the simple approach here. What makes that work is that `MID()` doesn't care if there exist 501 characters or if 250 exist after that. You get a blank, if not, rather than an error. So keep it simple, eh?

Each needs wrapped in an `IF()` test to see if a blank is returned and assign the unique value if it is, or let the result stand, if not). Column 1, for example:

```
=IF(LEFT(Sheet1!A2,250)="","PPP",LEFT(Sheet1!A2,250))
```

Same technique for all three columns. If you want to have everything blank below rows actually used (pointless for three easily examined columns, but maybe you'll do this with 320 columns someday), then wrap it all in another `IF()` that looks to see if the corresponding cell on `Sheet 1` is empty or not. What you return could be complicated, lots of possibilities, but if you don't mind returning the unique value, you could combine those two `IF()'s` into one testing an `AND()` of the two conditions. As mentioned, some other useful approaches could be taken as well.

So... now you have the data on `Sheet 2` and all nicely split as desired. `Copy` and `Paste|Special|Values` to make it data, not formulas, then `Search and Replace` the unique value with literally nothing specified in the `Replace` box to create true blanks so you have true `NULL's` after import.

Of course, have the formulas ready somewhere (`Sheet 3` maybe) for re-pasting in their places for any next use.

Finally, do your import.

Just a few simple formulas, making them values, making blank-looking cells real blanks, and you're done.